# Tags in javadoc comments for interface methods?

Tags: java, interface, comments, javadoc

I'm writing an interface in java, and I'm wondering if I should include tags in the interface's method's javadoc comments (@param, @return etc.) or if I should only include those tags in the implementing classes' method's javadoc comments. Here is an example:

I have an interface ShapeInterface, and there are implementing classes for shapes (Circle, Triangle, etc.)

So should javadoc comments appear like this?

```
public interface ShapeInterface{

/**
 * Sets the x-coordinate for this shape
 * @param x the x-coordinate for this shape
 */
public void setX(int x);

/**
 * Gets the x-coordinate of this shape
 * @return this.x the x-coordinate of this shape
 */
public int getX();
}
```

Or should they appear like below, with the tags only appearing in the javadoc comments of the implementing class's methods?

```
public interface ShapeInterface{

/**
 * Sets the x-coordinate for this shape
 */
public void setX(int x);

/**
 * Gets the x-coordinate of this shape
 *
public int getX();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, if `getX()` and `setX()` should do exactly the same thing for *all* shape types then you might want to consider inheriting from an abstract class rather than creating an interface. Alternatively, if using Java 8, make them default methods (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write Javadoc comments on all your interfaces and include the parameters as they are important!

The Javadoc comments should establish what the "contract" is that you want classes implementing the interface to meet and the parameters and returns are an important part of this contract.

It's the way anyone implementing your interface has information about how they should go about doing so.

Note that you may have to avoid being too specific when documenting interface methods where the exact action of an implementing class cannot be known.

If you're ever in doubt refer to the official Javadocs for Oracle's classes such as for the `List` interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Oracle have an excellent, relatively readable and comprehensive guide to Javadoc comments here:

[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Comment: Thanks, I was also wondering about specificity with regard to the value an implementing class returns, how is that addressed in Javadoc comments for the interface/superclass? Is an @return tag typically included there?

Comment: Implementing classes will *inherit* the javadocs of the interface unless they declare their own. If your subclass implements an interface often you don't need to Javadoc the method in the subclass if your interface javadocs are sufficient. If there is some subclass specific behaviour consider writing javadocs for the subclass. This page is pretty comprehensive guide to javadoc comments: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

Comment: By all means comment expected return values from methods with `@return` as this is also part of the "contract".